# Changing the variable assigned everytime a loop iterates

Tags: java, oop, object, for-loop

I am trying to build a program that allows the user to enter length and width of an object however many times I choose (I would build more code to choose how many times the loop goes). I am having some problems figuring out how to get input and construct an object every time the loop iterates. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter length" + i + ": ");
        int length i = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter length" + i + ": ");
        int width i = console.nextInt();

        OBJECT instance1 = new OBJECT(length1, width1);
    }


}
```

Comment: OBJECT shouldn't be done in all-caps. Anyway, I'd use an array. One third thing: It should be `int length = console.nextInt();`. The i is extraneous.

Comment: OBJECT isn't in all caps in my code, just changed it from my obscure actual name since I am not including the class.       Changing the length and widths to an array would work, but can that be done with the class constructor?

Comment: Yes, a constructor can take zero or more objects or primitives (excluding return_address which is only used internally). An array is an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList/LinkList, if your entries are big then only go for LinkList.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter how many records you want: ");
int j = console.nextInt(); //"Loop will run "+ j +" times"
List<ObjectName> objectList = new ArrayList<ObjectName>();
int length = 0;
int width = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
{
  System.out.println("Enter length" + i + ": ");
  length = console.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter width" + i + ": ");
  width = console.nextInt();
  ObjectName instance1 = new ObjectName(length, width);
  objectList.add(instance1);
}
```

Comment: *if your entries are big then only go for LinkList*: No. ArrayList is almost always a better choice. Oh, and it's *LinkedList*.

Comment: It's definitely not `ArrayListList`?

Comment: When I do it this way, and then try to use indexOf on the ArrayList it always returns an int instead of an object.

Comment: For that you need to use **get(int index)** method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how to use the Collections API, in particular `List`, `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`. So your code would become:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    final List<Area> objectList = new ArrayList<Area>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter length" + (i + 1) + ": ");
        final int length = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter width" + (i + 1) + ": ");
        final int width = console.nextInt();

        final Area instance = new Area(length, width);
        objectList.add(instance);
    }
}
```

I've choosen `ArrayList` here because it is normally the better performing one of the two (but for relatively small lists that do not require the functionality of either one, both will do).

Comment: ArrayList is almost always a better choice.

Comment: @JBNizet OK, changed it. As said, for small lists (user input would be one) it doesn't matter much, but it's probably better to get accustomed to using `ArrayList`.